# Carrierwave: Argument Error Nil location provided. Can't build URI for an image_tag using carrier wave Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I'm getting an argument error for Nil location provided when using the image_tag.  How do I make the image_tag optional where it only displays if there is a corresponding image?  This is with Ruby on Rails 5.

This is my current show page view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<%= image_tag @restaurant.image_url %>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @restaurant.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Address:</strong>
  <%= @restaurant.address %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Phone:</strong>
  <%= @restaurant.phone %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Website:</strong>
  <%= @restaurant.website %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_restaurant_path(@restaurant), class: 'btn btn-link' %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', restaurants_path, class: 'btn btn-link' %>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have two options.

1) Render image tag only if there is an image to be shown:

```
 <% if @restaurant.image_url %>
    <%= image_tag @restaurant.image_url %>
 <% end %>
```

2) Provide a default value for `image_url` field:

```
 <%= image_tag @restaurant.image_url || default_image %>
```

It's better to do it in a model/presenter:

```
class Image < ApplicationModel

  def image_url
    super || default_image
  end
end
```

Or with [attribute API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute):

```
class Image < ApplicationModel
  attribute :image_url, default: default_image
end
```

Comment: really helpful for me too.

Comment: It works man. I would choose solution creating a helper method and just call it anywhere I want :D

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the answers.

You can use a one-liner code for this:

```
<%= image_tag(@restaurant.image_url) if @restaurant.image_url%>
```

which is equivalent to:

```
<% if @restaurant.image_url? %>
  <%= image_tag(@restaurant.image_url) %>
<% end %>
```

**OR**

```
<% if @restaurant.image_url? %>
  <%= image_tag @restaurant.image_url %>
<% end %>
```

**Resources**: [Carrierwave - Making uploads work across form redisplays](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#making-uploads-work-across-form-redisplays)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 1):

This error is because image_tag argument is nil:

```
<%= image_tag nil %> # Nil location provided. Can't build URI
```

Answer (score 0):

use if condition, if there is an image it will display, if none, no error

```
   <% if @restaurant.image_url? %>
     <%= image_tag @restaurant.image_url %>
   <% end %>
```